# torch.rfft - fft-based convolution creating different output than spatial convolution

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, fft, convolution

I implemented FFT-based convolution in Pytorch and compared the result with spatial convolution via conv2d() function. The convolution filter used is an average filter. The conv2d() function produced smoothened output due to average filtering as expected but the fft-based convolution returned a more blurry output. 
I have attached the code and outputs here -

spatial convolution -

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("/kaggle/input/tiger.jpg")
im = im.resize((256,256))
gray_im = im.convert('L') 
gray_im = ToTensor()(gray_im)
gray_im = gray_im.squeeze()

fil = torch.tensor([[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9]])

conv_gray_im = gray_im.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
conv_fil = fil.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)

conv_op = F.conv2d(conv_gray_im,conv_fil)

conv_op = conv_op.squeeze()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(conv_op, cmap='gray')
```

FFT-based convolution -

```
def fftshift(image):
    sh = image.shape
    x = np.arange(0, sh[2], 1)
    y = np.arange(0, sh[3], 1)
    xm, ym  = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    shifter = (-1)**(xm + ym)
    shifter = torch.from_numpy(shifter)
    return image*shifter

shift_im = fftshift(conv_gray_im)
padded_fil = F.pad(conv_fil, (0, gray_im.shape[0]-fil.shape[0], 0, gray_im.shape[1]-fil.shape[1]))
shift_fil = fftshift(padded_fil)
fft_shift_im = torch.rfft(shift_im, 2, onesided=False)
fft_shift_fil = torch.rfft(shift_fil, 2, onesided=False)
shift_prod = fft_shift_im*fft_shift_fil
shift_fft_conv = fftshift(torch.irfft(shift_prod, 2, onesided=False))

fft_op = shift_fft_conv.squeeze()
plt.figure('shifted fft')
plt.imshow(fft_op, cmap='gray')
```

original image -

[image: original image]

spatial convolution output -

[image: convolution output]

fft-based convolution output -

[image: fft-conv output]

Could someone kindly explain the issue?

Comment: How do you generate `padded_fil`? Please see [mre]!

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that line. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that Torch doesn't do complex numbers, the output of its FFT is a 3D array, with the 3rd dimension having two values, one for the real component and one for the imaginary. Consequently, the multiplication does not do a complex multiplication.

There currently is no complex multiplication defined in Torch (see [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6514)), we'll have to define our own.

---

A minor issue, but also important if you want to compare the two convolution operations, is the following:

The FFT takes the origin of its input in the first element (top-left pixel for an image). To avoid a shifted output, you need to generate a padded kernel where the origin of the kernel is the top-left pixel. This is quite tricky, actually...

Your current code:

```py
fil = torch.tensor([[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9]])
conv_fil = fil.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
padded_fil = F.pad(conv_fil, (0, gray_im.shape[0]-fil.shape[0], 0, gray_im.shape[1]-fil.shape[1]))
```

generates a padded kernel where the origin is in pixel (1,1), rather than (0,0). It needs to be shifted by one pixel in each direction. NumPy has a function `roll` that is useful for this, I don't know the Torch equivalent (I'm not at all familiar with Torch). This should work:

```py
fil = torch.tensor([[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9]])
padded_fil = fil.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).numpy()
padded_fil = np.pad(padded_fil, ((0, gray_im.shape[0]-fil.shape[0]), (0, gray_im.shape[1]-fil.shape[1])))
padded_fil = np.roll(padded_fil, -1, axis=(0, 1))
padded_fil = torch.from_numpy(padded_fil)
```

---

Finally, your `fftshift` function, applied to the spatial-domain image, causes the frequency-domain image (the result of the FFT applied to the image) to be shifted such that the origin is in the middle of the image, rather than the top-left. This shift is useful when looking at the output of the FFT, but is pointless when computing the convolution.

---

Putting these things together, the convolution is now:

```py
def complex_multiplication(t1, t2):
  real1, imag1 = t1[:,:,0], t1[:,:,1]
  real2, imag2 = t2[:,:,0], t2[:,:,1]
  return torch.stack([real1 * real2 - imag1 * imag2, real1 * imag2 + imag1 * real2], dim = -1)

fft_im = torch.rfft(gray_im, 2, onesided=False)
fft_fil = torch.rfft(padded_fil, 2, onesided=False)
fft_conv = torch.irfft(complex_multiplication(fft_im, fft_fil), 2, onesided=False)
```

Note that you can do one-sided FFTs to save a bit of computation time:

```py
fft_im = torch.rfft(gray_im, 2, onesided=True)
fft_fil = torch.rfft(padded_fil, 2, onesided=True)
fft_conv = torch.irfft(complex_multiplication(fft_im, fft_fil), 2, onesided=True, signal_sizes=gray_im.shape)
```

Here the frequency domain is about half the size as in the full FFT, but it is only redundant parts that are left out. The result of the convolution is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I printed the padded kernel and it has its first value at (0,0), so after doing np.roll it is shifting some values to the last column and row of the image. So I don't see any problem with the kernel. The fft output of your code with this left-rolled kernel is some half-inverted and half-upright mixed image. Also, I had first done fft-based convolution without the fftshift function and it gave the same extra-blurry output as shown in the question but an inverted one (by 180 deg). So I did the fftshift part, and at least got an upright output.

Comment: @psj: The origin of the kernel is its center, if you define it otherwise you'll see a shifted output. Putting the center of the kernel at (0,0) causes a part of it (in this case 1 pixel) to appear on the right end and the bottom end of the image. For the FFT, the image is periodic.

Comment: @psj: OK, I installed Torch to figure out what is going on. It turns out that Torch doesn't understand complex numbers, which sort of makes it pointless to offer an FFT. I've updated this answer with working code, but all of this would be so much easier with a better tool. Use NumPy directly, or any of the real image processing packages out there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The IFFT output image now looks similar to the conv output. But when I print the two matrices - conv_op and fft_conv (I tried two crops for fft_conv to get an output equal to 'valid' convolution- one from the center and one from the top left), they don't seem to be equal - not even within a small error limit. Is this an approximation error between the two approaches? Also, which crop should I take from the IFFT output - I tried the center and top left but don't know which one should be taken logically.

Comment: @psj: The computations performed are very different, so the results will vary numerically because of that. The differences will increase towards the edges of the image, where the FFT convolution does something different than the spatial-domain convolution. You should display the difference between the two images `plt.imshow(conv_op-fft_conv)`. This should show an image without any detail of the original image, just (structured) noise.

Comment: For a (256,256) image and (3,3) kernel, the 'valid' convolution gives a (254,254) output. When I used the FFT approach by padding the kernel to (256,256) as above and cropped the center (254,254) part of the IFFT output, it was same as the convolution output with an error of 10^-8.  Also, when I used the FFT approach by padding both the image and kernel to (256+3-1,256+3-1), then the crop (1:255,1:255) of the IFFT output gave the same output as the 'valid' convolution output with an error margin of 10^-8. Could you kindly tell how to choose the crop of the IFFT?

Comment: psj: There’s no right way. What is right depends on your needs. 10^-8 is expected for the computational errors.

Comment: Yeah, I am fine with the error margin as it is negligible. What I wish to ask is which part of the IFFT output should we crop to obtain an output same as a 'valid' convolution? I tried different crops by trial and error, and the ones specified above gave me the same output as a 'valid' convolution - but I don't get the logic behind it, like why does the answer lie in this part of the IFFT output and not other parts.

Comment: The ‘valid’ convolution is usually defined as the region of the output where the kernel didn’t extend outside the input image region. If the convolution defines the kernel origin as in the middle of the kernel, then it is a border around the image of half the kernel width that is not valid, and cropped off. But it all depends on the definitions chosen by the implementer. Now that you’ve figured out which parts of the two outputs are equivalent, you know how to do it for this particular library. Other libraries might do the same, often they make the same choices, but you always need to check.